# Appcelerator tableviewsection top margin on iOS

Tags: ios, tableview, appcelerator-titanium

I have an ios app developed with titanium appcelerator. In the app I have some tablevies where I add some rows and some sections to create that sticky effect. But for some reason the sections have a top margin. Is there a way to remove that margin? The margin was not defined by me.

This is my TableView:

```
var mainView = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
        height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
        width: "100%",
        backgroundSelectedColor: 'transparent',
        backgroundSelectedColor: 'transparent',
        selectedColor: 'transparent',
        bottom: 0,
});
```

And the I add some TableViewSections to it:

```
tableData.push(Ti.UI.createTableViewSection({
        headerView: require("addStickyHeader").addStickyHeader(letra.toUpperCase()),
}));
```

The addStickyHeader function:

```
exports.addStickyHeader = function(text) {

var viewHeader = Ti.UI.createView({
    height : Ti.App.screenSize[0] * 0.08,
    width : "100%",
    backgroundColor : require("colors").fundo(),
    top : -100
});

viewHeader.add(Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text : text.toUpperCase(),
    color : require("colors").branco(),
    width : "84.6%",
    font : {
        fontSize : Ti.App.screenSize[0] * 0.019,
        fontFamily : require("fonts").semiBold()
    },
}));

return viewHeader;
```

};

That white parte should not be there.
[image]

Comment: This might be a default iOS margin. It would help if you could add parts of the code to have a better look and a screenshot to see the actual issue. Do you use a headerTitle or headerView for the sticky parts? headerView should be more flexible in styling

Comment: Are you sure that your TableView is starting at `top:0` and you are not seeing the background of your view? Also `top:- 100` looks not right. You can see that the black background is right at the flag in the first row and the second element has a space between the flag and separator line.

Comment: The top:-100 was a teste that I made trying to make the view go up. Yes I'm shore the table view starts at the top, I have changed the table views background and it goes till the top. The space between the flag and the separator are right I'm the second element. The problem is that the table view section get a top margin and it moves down. That is why it is touching the flag in the first element. That first one should have the same spaces as the second

Comment: sorry don't have an Mac to test but please run https://gist.github.com/m1ga/e61aa6acc7e7ff204fb6c204efcdef65 try https://titaniumsdk.com/api/titanium/ui/tableview.html#setcontentinsets and looking at native examples like https://github.com/maxsokolov/TableKit/issues/84#issuecomment-397448877 it sounds like a common "issue"